# Resolving conflicting type for functions with the same name in two external libraries

Tags: c, minix

I have included the following libraries into my code.

```
#include <minix/drivers.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <string.h>
```

Now I get the following error:

```
In file included from /usr/local/include/curl/curlbuild.h:152
                 from /usr/local/include/curl/curl.h:34
                 from xxx.c:2
/usr/pkg/gcc44/lib/gcc/i686-pc-minix/4.4.3/include-fixed/sys/socket.h:134: error: conflicting types for '_send'
/usr/include/minix/ipc.h:152: note: previous declaration was here
```

As far as I know this means that `_send` has been declared in two libraries (`minix/drivers.h` and `curl/curl.h`), I was wondering if it is possible to resolve this problem or work around it in some way?

Comment: There are several strategies in this discussion:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/678254/c-function-conflict

Comment: If I might ask, what exactly is your code going to be doing. It seems weird that this kind of overlap wouldn't have been run into before.

Comment: The problem is showing at compile time rather than link time.  Are you sure you need both `curl.h` and `drivers.h` in your program?

Comment: @Jon they are required as I need to load files from the web and mount a filesystem based on the external files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're on minix, you can modify one (or both) of the libraries with [`objcopy`](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/binutils/objcopy.html). From the man page:

> ```
> --redefine-sym old=new
>        Change the name of a symbol old, to new.  This can be useful when 
>        one is trying link two things together for which you have no source, 
>        and there are name collisions.
> ```

or, if you don't need `_send` from one of the libraries:

> ```
> -L symbolname
> --localize-symbol=symbolname
>        Make symbol symbolname local to the file, so that it is not visible 
>        externally.  This option may be given more than once.
> ```

Of course, you will need to update your headers accordingly. I would also recommend naming the modified library and headers something else so it's clear that you've modified them.

Comment: Precisely where is Linux indicated in the question?

Comment: Good point. I had erroneously thought minix was linux ([it isn't](http://www.minix3.org/)). However, [objcopy is still available](http://wiki.minix3.org/en/DevelopersGuide/NewBuildSystem).