# How to make a .lib file when have a .dll file and a header file

Tags: c++, dll, header, function

I am trying to create an application in visual studio that will be able to access a .dll file that already exists. I need the application to call up routines. I also have a header file that already exists.

I have been researching on the internet and have found that I need to create a .lib file. Looking at similar questions on here I found a link: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/131313
I cannot however follow the directions.

The information in the link says to make a DEF file ( I read elsewhere that this needs to be compiled as a DLL with the same name, but not sure what that name is, the same name as the .dll file?). But I do not understand the first direction, to 'Use DUMPBIN /EXPORTS'. I then need to 'stub out' functions, and then something to do with .OBJ files (I do not know what these files are).

Are there any step-by-step directions, similar to the link above, that are easy to follow?

Comment: With what compiler do you want to use the resulting lib with? Visual Studio? Which version?

Comment: I am aiming to use Microsoft Visual studio 2010 to be the application to use between the DLL and Matlab. The DLL is called Wintab32, it is found when you use a graphics tablet.

Answer (score 97):

You're going to need [Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Express](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/downloads) (or any other source of MSVC command line tools), and your DLL.

Steps:

1. `dumpbin /EXPORTS yourfile.dll > yourfile.exports`
2. Paste the names of the needed functions from `yourfile.exports` into a new `yourfile.def` file. Add a line with the word `EXPORTS` at the top of this file.
3. Run the following commands from `VC\bin` directory (the one where `lib.exe` and other compile tools reside).

```
 vcvars32.bat

 lib /def:yourfile.def /out:yourfile.lib
```

or for x64 builds

```
 lib /def:yourfile.def /machine:x64 /out:yourfile64.lib
```

You should get two files generated: `yourfile.lib` and `yourfile.exp`

Comment: Using `dumpbin.exe /EXPORTS yourfile.dll` for step 1 and 2 instead of Dependency Walker works just as well for obtaining the exported function names.

Comment: `dumpbin` failed for me ("LINK : fatal error LNK1328: table de chaînes manquante") so I used depends and created the def file by hand.

Comment: @jpo38 dumpbin works fine, that's just an environmental issue with your tooling installation

Answer (score 23):

You can use Digital Mars's [IMPLIB](http://digitalmars.com/ctg/implib.html) tool. It can create a lib file using only the dll, without any need for a .def file.

You can download it at https://ftp.digitalmars.com/bup.zip.

The command line is:

```
implib.exe /s mydll.lib mydll.dll
```

Comment: Thanks, I am having a look at this IMPLIB that you have suggested. Following the link, a line of code suggested is: implib /s kernel32.lib kernel32.dll  . I am a complete beginner with c++, how do I get started with implementing the code?

Comment: It's not the C++ code :) Just open up console (cmd) and execute implib using your dll (as shown in example with kernel32). Then get the resulting .lib file to the lib folder of your IDE (or to the projects folder & add the library path to the project). After that you will be free to use that library (just remember to keep the DLL is the same folder as the exe).

Comment: This blog seems explain it better
http://adrianhenke.wordpress.com/2008/12/05/create-lib-file-from-dll/
Or did you already try this? If yes, did it work?

Comment: Hi I used this method and got corrupted a file error in VS 2015. I had to use Sany Liew's solution to get the lib files working correctly.

Comment: I doubt if the Digital Mars solution will work.
Whereas VS uses the PE-COFF format, DM uses the OEM format which requires an extra step to convert to a form usable in VS.

Comment: Digital Mars Import Library Manager Version 7.6B1n
Copyright (C) Digital Mars 2000.  All Rights Reserved.

Error: Unexpected char 'F' in command line.

Comment: Error(10): Error: cannot read DLL input file

Answer (score 4):

There is a much simpler way to create a `.def` file. Search the web for the `gendef utility` (you may already have it if you have `Mingw-64`). Once you have it, just go to a command line and type,

```
gendef myfile.dll
```

And it will create a `myfile.def`. After that, just use `lib.exe` to create the `myfile.lib` file as explained by John.

Comment: Wow, thanks, that makes life a lot easier!
Btw there's also a gendef package in Cygwin.

Comment: lib.exe in msvc solved my problem. I just ran `lib.exe /DEF:.\src\build\windows\curl-windows\bin\libcurl-x64.def` and after that I could use the library and resolve the implementations/dependency/external symbol __imp__curl_easy_init by passing the resulting .lib file as an input: `cl.exe libcurl-x64.lib ...`

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution using [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/):

- install `gendef` and `mingw64-x86_64-binutils` Cygwin packages
- run in Cygwin console:

  ```
  gendef.exe awesome.dll
  x86_64-w64-mingw32-dlltool.exe -d awesome.def -l awesome.lib
  ```
- you get `awesome.lib` in the same dir.

VS 2019 linker linked just fine using this file.

Answer (score 0):

First type

#define YOURPROJECT_API _declspec(dllexport)

void yourf()

cpp

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "YOURPROJECT.H"
void yourf() {}
```

then include them

linker->input->def file then inhert from parent or project default

compile

Answer (score -1):

I might have the answer. I did this when I was creating a .exe console application that needed a .dll file. I ran into the problem as well. When I tried the IMPLIB application, it couldn't find any export files. You need to add an `#ifdef FILENAME_EXPORTS` (replace FILENAME with your .dll file name) and create an `_API`. Here is the code for the `#ifdef` export api commands:

```
#ifdef FILENAME_EXPORTS
#define FILENAME_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define FILENAME_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
```

Now that you have the Export API defined, you need to apply it to all the functions in your header file in the .dll project. For example:

```
void FILENAME_API function();
```

Declare your export functions normally, but include the API between the declarer type and the function name.

For defining the function in the .cpp file in the .dll project, you don't need the API in the declaration.

Here is an example of *filename*.h and *filename.cpp* with all the code.

```
// Code for filename.h
#pragma once

// Define your Export API
#ifdef FILENAME_EXPORTS
#define FILENAME_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define FILENAME_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

// Declare your functions with your API

void FILENAME_API function1();
void FILENAME_API function2();
void FILENAME_API function3();

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Code for filename.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "pch.h"
#include "filename.h"
using namespace std;

void function1()
{
    cout << "Hello Function1!";
}

void function2()
{
    cout << "Hello Function2!";
}

void function3()
{
    cout << "Hello Function3!";
}
```

Now when you compile the project, you should see the .dll, .lib, and .exp files in the folder where the compiled files are saved to. Now you can link the .exe file with the .lib file. You're Welcome!