# Directory of the release folder for dll generation

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, dll

I am linking dll with my app. It seems that there are no errors and it's being recognised in a good way.

but I am having an error of LINK 1181:

```
Error   3   error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'c:\users\xxx\Project\Release\mydll.lib
```

What could be the problem for that?

**Update:** I am getting a new message now which says the program can't start because tulips.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem!!!!

Comment: I do not understand the question. Does mydll.lib exist in the exact path that the linker is asking about? And what do you mean by a tulips file? BTW, through project settings you can control where your library is created.

Comment: @drescherjm the dll file is existing in the same path which is included in the error file.

Comment: The dll file does not count. You do not link against dll files. Does the file c:\users\xxx\Project\Release\mydll.lib" exist?

Comment: If the file does exist are you mixing 32 / 64 bit? You can not link a 32 bit lib to a 64 bit application or a 64 bit lib to a 32 bit application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that `mydll.lib` can not be found by the project. 
`LNK1181`: The linker could not find filename because it does not exist or the path was not found.
=> From the project, can you 2x click on it and see if VS2010 finds it?

Comment: I don't understand: which project shall I double click on? the dll or the app?

Comment: please check on the project referring to the `mydll.lib`

Comment: Just open up explorer and see if the file "c:\users\xxx\Project\Release\mydll.lib" exists

Comment: can you see the mydll.lib in the Solution explorer? if yes, 2x click on it: if found, VS will show you the binary representation. If not found, VS will display you a message similar to "lib not found"

Comment: @aah the mydll.lib is not existing. Only the .dll is existing!!

Comment: @drescherjm how can I generate then the .lib file?

Comment: @MelMed [answered here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9360280/how-to-make-a-lib-file-when-have-a-dll-file-and-a-header-file)

Comment: Visual Studio does create an import lib if you export your functions / classes correctly. I believe you do not get an import lib if nothing is exported.