# Visual studio C++ dll reference

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, dll, dllimport

I am working a application dev which uses API for a device. The API was downloaded with a dll file which i had to reference it in the project in visual studio 2017.

**But I am getting an error that the dll version cannot be used or not suitable be used for this project.**

So someone can pls help me out how can i reference a 3rd party dll file to a vs c++ project.

I have attached the error picture.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/godPP.jpg)

Comment: Have you tried to use a older version of Visual Studio, like 2013/2015?

Comment: yeah i used 2015. It also showed the same error.

Answer (score 0):

1. DLL has .lib file for linking the file and some headers to include in the library/source.You can use the methods and functions defined in the header files included in that dll file.
2. To add a link to the library just add the .lib file to the project config under Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies.

Comment: For this API they provided only a .dll file. No .lib files were supplied. They gave a .h file which I linked already.

Comment: @SenthilAthiban its possible but not easy to generate a lib file from a dll, the supplier of your dll should provide lib files.

Comment: @AlanBirtles can u tell the software name pls for generating the lib file from dll.

Comment: @SenthilAthiban see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9360280/how-to-make-a-lib-file-when-have-a-dll-file-and-a-header-file