# how to generate node.lib for native c++ addon (just like the library used in node-gyp) when build electron from source code

Tags: electron, native

I have built electron 4.1.4 from source code, but I don't know how to generate node.lib for native c++ addon. I build my c++ addon with the node.lib from https://atom.io/download/electron, but the electron which is built by me from source code can not load it.

I have build electron 4.1.4 from source code

there is no code

the step to generate node.lib (just like the download from https://atom.io/download/electron)

Comment: _Can not load_ is quite broad for an error description. Also, you might want to ask the guys over at ServerFault as this is not strictly a coding question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/18278

It is just electron.lib renamed to node.lib

Answer (score 0):

There's another way on win32 that I've done recently without rebuilding Electron from source.

First, generate `electron.lib` from `electron.exe` (or `node.exe`) by following this guide

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/16127548/23616342
- note that on your `.def` file, you should define the library as `electron.exe`

```
; electron.def

LIBRARY electron.exe
EXPORTS
  ; napi_... (export functions list)
```

Then link your addon with the generated `electron.lib`.

Quickly test your addon: `npx electron -r ./addon-name.node`

If you're packaging the app, you have to implement [win_delay_load_hook](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/using-native-node-modules#a-note-about-win_delay_load_hook) with filtering `electron.exe`.

```cpp
static FARPROC WINAPI load_exe_hook(unsigned int event, DelayLoadInfo* info) {
    HMODULE m;
    if (event != dliNotePreLoadLibrary)
        return NULL;

    if (_stricmp(info->szDll, "electron.exe") != 0)
        return NULL;

    m = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
    return (FARPROC)m;
}
```