# Force stdcall for imported methods

Tags: visual-c++, dllimport, dynamic-linking

I am trying to link against a dll, which is accompanied by a header file. Since there were no *.lib file available, I made one by manually creating a *.def file ([Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9360280/how-to-make-a-lib-file-when-have-a-dll-file-and-a-header-file))

Now the problem is, my test program is `__cdecl` and the methods in the dll are `__stdcall`.
Is there a way to force `__stdcall` for specific methods when they are dynamically linked?

Even though its not an option, tried changing the calling convention (`/Gd`) to `/Gz`, but the name mangling came up saying the linker failed to find the slightly mangled method as shown below.

```
LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _TSTInitialize@24 referenced in function
```

The function signature in header file is,

```
#define TSTPERC_API /*__declspec( dllimport ) __stdcall */  

TSTHandle cOpts;

    //call native methods
    TSTFunctionResult cResult = ::TSTInitialize(
        p_strPathToLib.c_str(), p_strConfigStruct.c_str(), p_strLic.c_str(),
        p_strRFU1.c_str(), p_strRFU2.c_str(), &cOpts );
```

Comment: The .def entry should probably be `TSTInitialize = TSTInitialize`.  Bit of a guess when we don't know the exported name.

Comment: well, sholdn't it be TSTInitialize=_TSTInitialize@24? i got it uptill _TSTInitialize but the @24 seems to get stripped off! Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you don't force `stdcall` on methods with incorrect ***.def*** or incorrect **.lib** files.

The `@24` in this case is the bytes on the stack the callee needs to cleanup. So there is no way around stripping it off (in case you do, then there is no way for the callee to know how many bytes to cleanup from the stack!! ).

The real problem was with the *.def file I created. The syntax is the other way around in my comment to @hans-passant,

```
TSTInitialize@24=TSTInitialize
```

This will make the correct export symbol, `_TSTInitialize@24` in the lib file `linker` is looking for. This helps reverting the program to use `/Gd` instead of `/Gz`