# Install OpenCV without lib file

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a version of OpenCV built with MinGW and I'm trying to include it in a Visual Studio project. I have the dlls and the header files, however no lib files were provided. Only dll.a files. I tried pointing the linker additional dependencies setting to the dll.a files however I still get unresolved external symbol errors.

How do I use this version of OpenCV if it doesn't have the lib files?

Note: I should mention, I'm trying to use this specific build because it is x86, which is what I need for this project, and the official site doesn't seem to provide x86 builds.

Comment: There is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9360280/how-to-make-a-lib-file-when-have-a-dll-file-and-a-header-file). But you are going to have problems if you are planning to use anything not exported as extern "C".

Comment: Recompile opencv with vc compiler, or use a pre-built one

Comment: @ChrisD I'll look into this

Comment: @Miki I'm trying to use a pre-built one, but there is no .lib file for me to include (only dll.a files) which results compilation errors. I don't know how else to include this build in my project. The official builds don't seem to have x86 versions.