# How does the C++ standard library work behind the scenes?

Tags: c++, std

This question has been bothering me so much for the past couple of days. I was wondering how the standard library works, in terms of functionality. I couldn't find an answer anywhere, even by checking the [source code](https://code.woboq.org/llvm/include/c%2B%2B/7/) provided by the LLVM compiler which is, for a beginner like me, a really complicated piece of code.

What I'm basically trying to understand here is how does the C++ standard library work. For example let's take the `fstream` header file which consist of a bunch of functions that help to write to and read from files.

How does it work? Does it use the OS specific API (since the library is cross platform), or what? And, if the standard library can do it, aren't I supposed to be able to mess with some files as well without calling the standard `fstream` file (which to my experience I can't do)?

*I apologize if my questions are unclear since I'm not a native English speaker: feel free to modify this text so as to make it clearer.*

Comment: The interface of the standard library is cross-platform. The implementation generally isn't. Yes of course is ultimately uses facilities provided by the operating system.

Comment: You too can use the API provided by the operating system, if you don't care about your program being portable.

Comment: There are different implementations of STL available. Visual Studio has theirs. GCC has theirs, etc. Typically most C++ already works cross-platform, but code can be specialized to take advantage of certain OS features.

Comment: I think this is on-topic. A clear, well written programming question that has a technical, non-subjective answer. Voted to reopen.

Comment: You don't need to use the C++ standard library.  It just exists to make your code cross platform.  For example - to open a file you can use std::fstream or you can just call the OS specific function that the standard library calls (on Windows it is CreateFileA if you are using ASCII.  You don't even need a header file and you can create the link library from the kernel32.dll that is part of the Windows OS

Comment: So for kernel32.dll for example: you can make a kernel32.h file by cutting and pasting each individual function's declaration from Microsoft's web site ( for CreateFileA it is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilea ) and then you can make the kernel32.lib link library by following the instructions at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9360280/how-to-make-a-lib-file-when-have-a-dll-file-and-a-header-file  and then you can write a program that includes your kernel32.h and links against you kernel32.lib and doesn't use anything else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does it use the OS specific API (since the library is cross platform), or what?

At some point, the OS specific API is used. The `fstream` implementation does not necessarily call an OS function directly. It might use other classes, which call functions inherited from C, etc., but eventually the call chain will lead to an OS call. *(Yes, the details are often too complicated for an intermediate programmer to follow. So, as a self-described beginner, your findings are not surprising.)*

The library is cross-platform in the sense that on your end (the C++ programmer), the interface is the same regardless of platform. It is not, however, the same library on every platform. Each platform has its own library, exposing the same interface on the C++ side, but making use of different OS calls. (In fact, the same platform might have multiple standard libraries, as the library implementation is provided by your toolchain, not by the standards committee.)

> And, if the standard library can do it, aren't I supposed to be able to mess with some files as well without calling the standard `fstream` file (which to my experience I can't do)?

Yes, you are allowed to. Apparently, you have not been able to yet, but with some practice and guidance you should be able to. Everything in the standard library can be recreated in your own code. The point of the standard library (and most libraries, for that matter) is to save you time, not to enable something that was otherwise unavailable. For example, you don't have to implement a file stream for every program you write; it's in the standard library so you can focus on more interesting aspects of your project.

Comment: I hope the text is clear enough. I've been told that my writing style can be rough for non-native speakers to follow. I did try to tone it down a bit. Apologies if it was not enough.

Answer (score 2):

A compiler is just a program which create executable file or library. You can use the compiler default libraries to gain time or write your own. The default libraries communicate with the os for file operation or memory allocation and provide a simple standard classes to allow the developper to write only one code which work on all target platforms supported by the compiler and the libraries. If you want to write your own you have to write each function for all your target os.

Answer (score 2):

The standard library is cross-platform in a sense that its interface does not change between platforms but its implementation does - or in practical terms - if you only use C++ and its standard library, you can write your code the same way for *Linux* / *Windows* / *MacOS* / *Android* / *Whatever* and if you find a C++ compiler for one of those platforms that supports the language features you used, you will be able to compile your code for that platform without rewriting anything.

So while you can use `std::vector` or `std::fstream` or any other feature in the library independently of the platform you're writing for and expect the function definitions, type names, etc. to look the same, you cannot expect the executable which you compiled for PC with Windows 10 to run on a phone with Android. You cannot even expect the same executable to run on the same PC but with different system - that is what I mean by "the implementation is different"

There are two main reasons for this difference:

1. Processors with different architectures (x86-64 and ARM for example) use different instruction sets and as such the C++ source would need to be compiled to a completely different machine code to run properly
2. Computers with processors of the same architecture which have a different operating system have different ways of dynamically allocating memory, creating files, creating streams, writing to console, creating and scheduling threads etc. - which is part of the system functionality that you use via the standard library

If you really wanted to you could use [`HeapAlloc()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/heapapi/nf-heapapi-heapalloc) instead of `operator new()` or [`CreateThread()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createthread) instead of stdlib's `std::thread` but that would force you to both rewrite your program every time you wanted to compile it for something else than Windows and recompile it with the target platform's compiler (and by proxy learn its API). Standard library saves you from that trouble by abstracting away those system calls.

As for the `fstream` in particular, [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/using-streams) is what it uses internally on most PCs nowadays.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, `fstream`, `iostream` and `printf` works based on a kernel function `write()`. When your code call `printf` (we use `printf` as an example), it will finally call `write()` to let the kernel work on the IO stuff. After that, `write()` returns and `printf` returns and your code continues.

So if you really want to know how the `printf` works internally, you have to read the source code of the Kernel.

**But you shouldn't do that for now.**

For a beginner, do not try to go deeper when you haven't got a basic cognition about computer. A computer is a project, just like a building. So the right way to learn it is to learn it level by level. First, learning how to use brick and cement to build a building, this is what you should do for now. What you shouldn't do is that you are learning how to build a building and this is your first time to try to use brick, then you are interested in how to produce a brick and start to focus on brick, this is a wrong way to learn IT.

If you are learning C/C++, just learn it. Remember, learn it **level by level**. For now, knowing how to use `printf` is enough.

Comment: Re: "based on a kernel function `write()`" -- maybe, if the kernel has it. But to understand how `printf` works internally, the place to start is the source code for `printf`.