# C link error with created .lib from .dll using dumpbin.exe

Tags: c, windows

Following this guide [How to make a .lib file when have a .dll file and a header file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9360280/how-to-make-a-lib-file-when-have-a-dll-file-and-a-header-file) I create the `.lib` file from `.dll`. For the `.dll` I have only a header file.
After linking the library and call one from the function i got `fatal error LNK1120`.

Actually i use the `.dll` with the `LoadLibrary()` method. All functions listed from `dumpbin /EXPORTS RFC1006Lib.dll` can used with `GetProcAddress()`. So the functions exist and work.
I tried the `.lib` in MSVC 2022 and Mingw32 with same result. Next I use `implib.exe` to generate `.lib` but in this case booth compilers say the format is wrong.

The `.dll` is downloaded from here: https://www.traeger.de/products/development/rfc1006/native/rfc1006-lib#downloads

How i try to compile the APP:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "isootcp/rfc.lib") //created lib from lib.exe and dumpbin.exe
#pragma comment(lib, "WS2_32.lib")

#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <winsock.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <io.h>
#include "isootcp/rfc1006lib.h" //given header from developer

void main(void)
{
long WINAPI handle = Rfc1006Open("10.196.72.5", "Erzer\0", 5, "TCP-1\0", 5, 0, 5000);
printf("Handle Result: %lu\n", handle);
}
```

Following the created `.def` for `lib.exe`:

```
EXPORTS
Rfc1006Close
Rfc1006Connect
Rfc1006Disconnect
Rfc1006GetSockErr
Rfc1006GetSockErrString
Rfc1006GetStatus
Rfc1006Open
Rfc1006OpenExServer
Rfc1006OpenServer
Rfc1006PacketInQ
Rfc1006Rx
Rfc1006SetFastAck
Rfc1006SetKeepAlive
Rfc1006StartServer
Rfc1006StopServer
Rfc1006Tx
Rfc1006TxUnlocked
```

I expect to link a working `.lib` in my project. I don´t like the `LoadLibrary` solution (create seperate header and much more work comparing with librarys).

Comment: why would you need to create a .lib yourself? the package you linked already has it along with the dlls and header files.