# Executable doesn't see Vulkan dynamic lib and throws an linker-error LNK2019

Tags: cmake, dll, linker-errors, vulkan, dynamic-linking

I wanted to write an application in C++/Vulkan without requiring the pre-installed [VulkanSDK](https://vulkan.lunarg.com/sdk/home).

So, I have added through "git submodule" [vulkan-headers](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Headers) repo, copy VulkanRT to binaries-directory and wrote CMake lists for the project.

Project Hierarchy:

```
root/
     binaries/
         vulkan-1.dll
     src/
         main.cpp
         CMakeLists.txt - list that makes an executable
     CMakeLists.txt - main list
```

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20 FATAL_ERROR)

project(proj LANGUAGES C CXX)

set(VULKAN_DLL ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/binaries/vulkan-1.dll)

add_subdirectory(vendor) # builds deps
add_subdirectory(src)
```

src/CMakeLists.txt:

```
set(PROJECT_SOURCE
    main.cpp
)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${PROJECT_SOURCE})

set(INCLUDE_DIR ../vendor)
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
    ...
)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE
    ...
)

set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES
    CXX_STANDARD 20
    CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED On
)

# Command that copies a vulkan-1.dll in exec directory
add_custom_command(
    TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} PRE_BUILD
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy
    ${VULKAN_DLL}
    $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:${PROJECT_NAME}>
)
```

And after building an project I caught a linking error:

```
C:\dev\octo>cmake -B=build -S=.
-- Including Win32 support
-- GLM: Version 0.9.9.9
-- Build spdlog: 1.12.0
-- Build type:
CMake Deprecation Warning at vendor/tinyobjloader/CMakeLists.txt:4 (cmake_minimum_required):
  Compatibility with CMake < 3.5 will be removed from a future version of
  CMake.

  Update the VERSION argument <min> value or use a ...<max> suffix to tell
  CMake that the project does not need compatibility with older versions.


-- Configuring done (0.1s)
-- Generating done (0.1s)
-- Build files have been written to: C:/dev/octo/build

C:\dev\octo>cmake --build build
MSBuild version 17.7.2+d6990bcfa for .NET Framework

  glfw.vcxproj -> C:\dev\octo\build\vendor\glfw\src\Debug\glfw3.lib
  imgui.vcxproj -> C:\dev\octo\build\vendor\Debug\imgui.lib
  spdlog.vcxproj -> C:\dev\octo\build\vendor\spdlog\Debug\spdlogd.lib
  tinyobjloader.vcxproj -> C:\dev\octo\build\vendor\tinyobjloader\Debug\tinyobjloader.lib
device.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol vkCreateInstance referenced in function "private: void __cdecl O
cto::Device::CreateInstance(void)" (?CreateInstance@Device@Octo@@AEAAXXZ) [C:\dev\octo\build\src\octo.vcxproj]
```

[Caught linking error after build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9QdUG.png)

Building for Windows, conf: MVSC 2022 Release - amd64
Building though commands:
cmake -B=build -S=.
cmake --build build

I just tried do something like that.

```
set(BIN_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/binaries)
if(WIN32)
    set(ENV{PATH} "${BIN_DIR};$ENV{PATH}")
endif()
```

And I also tried `install()` command, nothing helps.

Custom copy command literally copies vulkan-1.dll to executable folder, but linkage stage falling with error LNK2019

Comment: @Tsyvarev I guess I'll leave image and append error via text.

Comment: The error message means that linker has taken into account all libraries, which you have passed to it, but none of that libraries defines the missed function. In the posted CMake code I see no linkage with the vulkan library (by using `target_link_libraries` or so). Whether `.dll` is copied into the directory with the executable is absolutely **irrelevant** for that kind of errors.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Do we need to **explicitly** specify dependencies in `target_link_libraries`? I'm using a `DLL`, and it should theoretically attempt to resolve its dependencies at runtime, am I wrong?

Comment: "it should theoretically attempt to resolve its dependencies at runtime" - Windows resolves at runtime only those dependencies, which are specified for executable. For specify a library file as a dependency, you need **explicitly** pass name of that file to the linker.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Okey, how should I do that? Add to `target_link_libraries` line `PRIVATE vulkan-1`? If I do this then I will get linker error, because he will not see `vulkan-1.lib` file.
Like this `LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'vulkan-1.lib'`

Comment: You need to have `.lib` file, otherwise you cannot use that library. When talk about shared library, a `.lib` file is the **export file**. See also that question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9360280/how-to-make-a-lib-file-when-have-a-dll-file-and-a-header-file

Comment: Does it mean that Vulkan library cannot be used without Vulkan SDK because it is a lower-level API, and without vulkan-1.lib, the program doesn't know how to utilize this library?

Comment: Yes, without vulkan-1.lib, the program doesn't know how to utilize this library.

Answer (score 0):

If you came across this question because you are also looking to create a standalone Vulkan application and find that attempting to solve this issue like a regular library isn't working.

Here's the answer why!

Vulkan is a low-level API that provides functions. These functions call proc.addresses with GPU functions available on your graphics card. If you want to play a game that uses the Vulkan API, you don't need to rush and download the Vulkan SDK, right? Now, let's get into the details.

When you update your GPU vendor drivers, Vulkan is installed by default as one of opportunities to call GPU functions. HOWEVER, this Vulkan installation is a collection of functions and handlers like PFN_vkCreate, which calls an actual GPU function. The vulkan-1.lib file abstracts them into functions that you are familiar with if you have worked with Vulkan API before.

So, are we unable to use Vulkan as a standalone application?

No, we can.

For that purpose (this is what I found):

1. [**Vulkan-Headers**](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Headers) and [**Vulkan-Loader**](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Loader). The first one contains Vulkan headers, and the second one is the actual library that can retrieve function handlers from your GPU and load them as VulkanAPI.
2. [**volk**](https://github.com/zeux/volk.git). That library as I noticed that solution will work without any reference to vulkan.h header-files and etc. That library gets GPU handlers and provides own function for instantiation, getting devices list, device creation, queues and more. (Not sure about layers)
3. **Do it yourself**. You could get and store actual Vulkan procedures that call actual GPU functions. It will look like this: `(PFN_vkGetDeviceProcAddr)vkGetInstanceProcAddr(inst, "vkGetDeviceProcAddr");`

Thus far, this is all I know about the capabilities of loading Vulkan API at runtime. I hope this information helps you understand Vulkan a bit better and the possibilities of implementing applications using dynamic Vulkan. Thank you for your attention.

Comment: @solidpixel okey, lmao.