# Static library hides symbols from other static library

Tags: c++, visual-c++

My .exe-project depends on external static libraries A.lib and B.lib.

**The problem**: Library B internally also uses library A and exports its symbols. But the version of A used is different from A.lib - and incompatible with my app.

When linking my application with both A.lib and B.lib, the A-symbols included in
B.lib hide the proper symbols in A.lib. Although linking succeeds, my app doesn't work correctly.

Factoring out all usage of B.lib into another static library C.lib doesn't help: C.lib still exports all symbols from B.lib.

Can this be solved without the following workarounds?

- Dynamic linking.
- Re-building B with my version of A.lib. (I have access to the source of B.)

  This might cause unknown side-effects in B.

(In my concrete case A.lib is [Freetype](http://freetype.sourceforge.net/index2.html) and B.lib is [SFML](http://www.sfml-dev.org/) - but the issue is universal.)

Comment: Look at the answer of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/678254/c-function-conflict.

Comment: This problem is a bit more intricate: I need to link different versions of the same symbol into one executable.

Comment: You could rename symbols from one version of `A.lib` and use in one of `B.lib` or the `.exe` to avoid conflicts.