# Two .lib containing different functions with the same name: how to choose the right one?

Tags: c++, c, static-libraries

I have two static libraries lib1.lib, lib2.lib (not their code) with the same function-prototypes, but with different implementations.

I tried including both, and it seems to use always the implementation from the first library included.

If I include both of them in my project, is there a way to choose the implementation from a specific library?

Comment: Your libraries should have namespaces around their functions. Try using these namespaces. And if your libraries don't have namespaces, try using different libraries!

Comment: Unfortunately the libraries have no namespaces.

Comment: Sound like a violation of the [ODR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_definition_rule), in which case there is no legal solution AFAIK.

Comment: What platform are you on?

Comment: Windows7 64bit, VisualStudio2012

Comment: @DanielFrey That's not correct. If they are static libraries, the linker will resolve any dependency with the first match it finds. It is perfectly valid to have multiple symbols with the same name in different static libraries. However, the linking order then determines which of them gets picked.

Comment: @MichaelWild That is how it works with GCC, so I expect it to be the same in MSVC. The OP should try to reverse the order of the libraries in the include path. Unfortunately, I don't see any clever way to make use of both of them in the same project, so it's probably pointless to include both of them anyway.

Comment: @MichaelWild: This is what happens in practice and it is compiler/system dependent, but it's still a violation of the ODR. Read point 2 of the summary on Wikipedia (link in my first comment) or §3.2/3 of the C++ standard.

Comment: @DanielFrey I think this is not clearly covered by the standard which is mainly concerned about single translation units and the final program, but doesn't really talk about linking. In my reading the behavior of popular linkers w.r.t. to multiple definitions in distinct static libraries is standards compliant.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C function conflict](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/678254/c-function-conflict)

Comment: @MichaelWild I disagree: In the linked question the libraries are dynamic libraries.

Comment: @888 But the answers talk about both.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it should be possible to write thin wrapper DLL's that link against each of the static libraries. Notice that this will only work if `lib1.lib` and `lib2.lib` are static libraries and that such a wrapping will incur a performance hit.

Comment: Good idea! I'll try it and I'll let you know about the performances!

Comment: On Linux you could use `objcopy --redefine-sym oldsym newsym libfile`, no idea whether Windows has something similar.