# Include static library within a preprocessor directive

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, static-libraries

I'm using Visual Studio 2012.

I used many times preprocessor directives like

```
#ifdef something 
      #include<some_header.h>
#else
      #include<other_header.h>
#endif
```

I was wondering if is possible to link a static library in a similar way:

```
#ifdef something 
      // use some_library.lib
#else
      // use other_library.lib
#endif
```

The question, came from the subject of my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15497220/two-lib-containing-different-functions-with-the-same-name-how-to-choose-the-ri): I have two static libraries lib1.lib, lib2.lib (not their code) without namespaces, with the same function-prototypes, but with different implementations.

Comment: What you are asking for is madness. Two libraries means nothing if they don't have the same method signatures, and if they do have the same method signatures, this should probably be a runtime setting that is flipped (such as logging or other debug info)

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII it's a perfectly valid situation. E.g., linking against debug library vs. release library. It's usually done not by #pragmas but via project configuration.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are using MSVC you can do

```
#ifdef something 
      #pragma comment(lib,"xxx.lib")
#else
      #pragma comment(lib,"zzz.lib")
#endif
```

In GCC you cannot do this.