# How to use two libraries if they have same function in C?

Tags: c, function, duplicates

I found some discussion, the answer is using static, another answer is renaming the function

but, if I don't have source code, how can I rename the function?

I also tried the static, but not work, error: "warning #2135: Static 'func' is not referenced."

What is the correct solution?

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "liba.h"
#include "libb.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("Main\n");
    func();
    return 0;
}
```

liba.h

```
static void func(void);
```

liba.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "liba.h"

static void func(void)
{
    printf("lib a\n");
}
```

libb.h

```
static void func(void);
```

libb.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "libb.h"

static void func(void)
{
    printf("lib b\n");
}
```

Comment: You can't. C doesn't have namespaces, so the functions in both libs are going to conflict.

Comment: i think this is the solution for you  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/678254/c-function-conflict

Comment: C doesn't show polymorphic behaviour, Why don't you put some letters of library name in your function name to make it distinct?

Answer (score 1):

In C header file function are global and cause conflict if are of same name. You need to change the name to avoid conflict.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done, but not directly. You need to abstract away the offending duplicate function behind a wrapper. As described by the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/678254/c-function-conflict) (linked by Jayesh):

> If you don't control either of them you can wrap one of them up. That
>   is compile another (statically linked!) library that does nothing
>   except re-export all the symbols of the original except the offending
>   one, which is reached through a wrapper with an alternate name.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it as far as I know. I am not saying it is not possible, but impractical as 'c' doesn't allow `polymorphism`    and  `namespaces`. And yes the link shared by Jayesh is informative have a look [What should I do if two libraries provide a function with the same name generating a conflict?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/678254/c-function-conflict)