# how do you link one function with the same name present in two shared lib

Tags: function, shared-libraries

i have an executable which use two shared lib(shar1.so, shar2.so)
the shared lib use use same static lib(stat.a)

but that is not creating any linker errors as multiple definations.

not able to get the reason.

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/678254/what-should-i-do-if-two-libraries-provide-a-function-with-the-same-name-generati/678309#678309

Answer (score 0):

> not able to get the reason.

The reason is very simple: shared libraries on UNIX are designed to behave the same way archive libraries behave.

Suppose you have `foo1.o` which defines function `foo`, and `foo2.o` that also defines `foo` (perhaps with different implementation). Suppose you put `foo1.o` into `libfoo1.a` and `foo2.o` into `libfoo2.a`.

If you understand how UNIX linkers [work](http://webpages.charter.net/ppluzhnikov/linker.html) with [archive libraries](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2013/07/09/library-order-in-static-linking), you can predict what would happen when you link your program like this:

```
gcc -o t main.o -L. -lfoo1 -lfoo2   # or
gcc -o t main.o -L. -lfoo2 -lfoo1
```

Well, if you now link `foo1.o` into `libfoo1.so` and `foo2.o` into `libfoo2.so`, and use above commands, the *exact same behavior* will happen (even though details of *how* that behavior will happen are very different).