# Symbol conflict in transitive dependencies of two dynamic libraries

Tags: c, linux, linker, elf, dynamic-loading

I am using two third party dynamic libraries: `liba.so` and `libb.so`. They both call a function named `common` included in another dynamic library, but `liba.so` should use the one from `libsuba.so` while `libb.so` the one from `libsubb.so`.

I have no access to the source code of these dynamic libraries and I am thus unable to change the function name of one library and recompile it to resolve the conflict.

I am aware that macOS provides a two level namespace that seems to solve the issue, but I didn't found anything similar in `ld` man pages.

```c
// exe.c
extern void func_a(void);
extern void func_b(void);

void main(void) {
    func_a();
    func_b();
}
```

```c
// lib(a|b).c
extern void common(void);

void func_(a|b)(void) {
    common();
}
```

```c
// libsub(a|b).c
#include <stdio.h>

void common(void) {
    printf("Common (A|B)\n");
}
```

```
all: exe

exe: exe.c liba.so libb.so
    gcc -L. -Wl,-rpath=. -o $@ $< -la -lb

liba.so: liba.c libsuba.so
    gcc -shared -fPIC -Wl,-rpath=. -L. -o $@ $< -lsuba

libb.so: libb.c libsubb.so
    gcc -shared -fPIC -Wl,-rpath=. -L. -o $@ $< -lsubb

libsub%.so: libsub%.c
    gcc -shared -fPIC -o $@ $<
```

Is there any way to solve this issue?

Edit: The current output value is:

```
$ ./exe 
Common A
Common A
```

and I would like the output to be:

```
$ ./exe 
Common A
Common B
```

Comment: `LD_PRELOAD=libsubb.so`. Also see [What is the LD_PRELOAD trick?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/426230/608639) and [`ld.so(8)`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/ld-linux) man page.

Comment: It forces the `common` function to be the one from `libsubb.so`.
I would like `func_a` to use the `common` function from `libsuba.so` and `func_b` the one from `libsubb.so`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should report the issue to the respective vendors of those libraries. I think they are missing namespaces for exported symbols (for sure, if `libsuba` and `libsubb` both export a symbol called "common").

Have you thought about using `objcopy --redefine-sym` (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/678375/2104472))? However, objcopy does not seem to modify the dynamic symbol talbe, rendering this approach useless :(

Comment: `objcopy` indeed seem to update only `.symtab` and not `.dynsym`. I reported the issue and in the meantime, I will try to load one of the two libraries using `dlsym()` and `RTLD_LOCAL` hoping that the lookup scopes are different (they are according to dsohowto.pdf).