# Include global function in namespace in C++

Tags: c++

Is there a way to include global functions (say from a library where I'm not allowed to modify the code) in to a namespace's scope and still be able to use it?

I have two functions:

```
base64_decode()
base64_encode()
```

in two files: `Base64.cpp` `Base64.h`.

(Obviously) when including `Base64.h` in to my `Extensions` namespace, the function declarations are available, but the linker can't find the definitions (in `Base64.cpp`) because they're now included in my namespace. Example:

```
namespace Extensions {
    #include "Base64.h"
}
```

Is there a way to have both the implementation and the declaration of the two functions inside the namespace **without** modifying the original code and **without** `#include`ing `Base64.cpp`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One common way:

```
#include "Base64.h"

namespace Extensions {

using ::base64_decode;
using ::base64_encode;

}

static_assert(sizeof(&Extensions::base64_decode) > 0, "");
static_assert(sizeof(&Extensions::base64_encode) > 0, "");
```

Comment: Your edit answered the question if I can then use the functions as if they were part of the namespace. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to get the functions *into* the namespace, then [Maxim Egorushkin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/412080/maxim-egorushkin)'s excellent answer is the way to go.

Sometimes however, you need to get the function *out* of the global namespace (because it conflicts with another function of the same name).  In that case you are going to have to use

```
namespace Extensions {
    #include "Base64.h"
}
```

and then use platform specific hacks to rename the symbols in the library so that the linker can find them.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/678254/c-function-conflict/678375#678375) for Linux.

It looks like all the options to rename symbols on Windows apply to DLLs.  You will have to work out what the name-mangling is.

Comment: @SimonC accept the answer that is helpful *for you*.  If having the symbols in the global namespace is OK for you, than accept Maxim's.  If not, then mine (or write your own with more details of the "platform specific hacks").  Different people will have different requirements, so multiple answers are fine.