# Boostrap modal show triggering colorbox modal

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, colorbox

I have colorbox and boostrap libraries added and every time I perform a

```
$('#selector').modal('show');
```

It opens Boostrap modal and then when I close Boostrap's it opens colorbox modal.

Is there any way to prevent this without removing colorbox src?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What should I do if two libraries provide a function with the same name generating a conflict?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/678254/what-should-i-do-if-two-libraries-provide-a-function-with-the-same-name-generati)