# Way to fix the multiple definition link error

Tags: c++, gcc

I'm using two static libraries that are developed by two other teams.

When trying to build my app, i got "multiple definition for two classes" the first in liba.a the second is in libb.a

Is there a way to fix this issue?
I do not have the source of the two libraries, so I cannot change the namespaces

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What should I do if two libraries provide a function with the same name generating a conflict?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/678254/what-should-i-do-if-two-libraries-provide-a-function-with-the-same-name-generati)

Comment: Thank you for your help, unfortunately no, I have an issue with classes here.

Comment: Please provide [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).