Problem with ambiguity of functions from different libraries - multiple CMakeLists.txt?
I'm working on a project, with CMake, that uses mainly two different libraries:

ROOT: https://root.cern/
OpenCASCADE: https://dev.opencascade.org/

When I try compiling I get errors of ambiguity. Basically both the libraries have the same Printf function (and possibly others). Gladly the libraries are not called in the same scripts, and I could therefore isolate one from the other.
I tried reading a lot before asking here, and some of the solutions I found consist of editing one of the libraries by changing the function name, but I'm afraid of going in that direction and messing up with the library. Furthermore, the functions that are ambiguous are base libraries, and I cannot call one of them by e.g. ROOT::TString::Printf or using typedef.
So I thought of a couple of different approaches:

Compile separately as completely different projects, and call the executable of one of the subprojects from the other by means of std::system("./executable"); - I find this cumbersome, as I think I'd maybe need a bash macro to compile everything separately;
Edit my CMakeLists.txt to call the libraries separately;

For the latter case, I've read a lot about it, but it's definitely not clear to me how to set this up. I know that there are options such option and set in order to do so, but can't seem to make it right.
Which approach should I take, and if it's the latter, how to do it?

are you saying that both libraries define a function called Printf (with capital P) in the top namespace?

in the same scripts C++ is not a script language. are base libraries what is a "base library"?

Is your problem with linking to said libraries, as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/678254/what-should-i-do-if-two-libraries-provide-a-function-with-the-same-name-generati ? If so, CMake won't help: in the end it will have to launch linker anyways and the problem doesn't have a neat solution.

@alfC: It seems :/ open cascade Printf and root's one

Unfortunately, having both libraries lead to ODR-violation. they are incompatible. If only they use namespace.

"Gladly the libraries are not called in the same scripts" C++ doesn't have script, you have to clarify your setup. Are both libraries used in same project, or in different projects. if the later, you might have clean solution. For the former, hacking seems the only way...

@Jarod42, worst of all, probably both functions want to do the same. Not sure if this is the case, but if one overwrite the other might not even be a problem. I am curious if there is any solution.

Thanks for the inputs. By "same scripts" I mean that I don't call the headers of both libraries in the same file. Thus I mentioned that I could compile each file separately, and call one from the other using the system library.
And yes, both libraries are used in the same project. I guess I have to hack it :)

@lghizoni Are these shared libraries in your linkage, not static libraries?
